# Get MVC Validation Attribute Adapters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to pull the Client Validation Rules from a ValidationAttribute. The validator in question has Client Validation Rules attached via a DataAnnotationsModelValidator attached as an adapter using DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter.

However, I can't figure out for the life me how to get the adapters back at run time.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, Andrew

Comment: what do you mean saying "get the adapters back at run time"?

Comment: Probably not the best choice of words. I really just meant retrieve those that are attached by a DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter.

Comment: I'm not sure you can get that easily because they are stored into an internal dictionary. A better option would be keeping track of the adapters added to the provider yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use reflection to get the `MemberInfo` object of the property with the attribute. Then,

```
// given memberInfo, controllerContext, and modelMetadata 
// (see below on how to get metadata)
foreach (var attribute in memberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValidationAttribute), true)
{
    var clientValidationAttribute = attribute as IClientValidatable;
    if (clientValidationAttribute == null)
    {
        continue;
    }

    var clientValidationRules = clientValidationAttribute.GetClientValidationRules(modelMetadata, controllerContext);

    // do something with the rules
}
```

To get model metadata, you can call

```
ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, viewData)
```

if you have viewdata handy. You can also get it by explicitly invoking a ModelMetadataProvider. Let me know if you need more specifics.

Comment: That will get you the rules that are added as part of IClientValidatable directly to the Attribute. I'm asking about rules added by registering a DataAnnotationsModelValidator using DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example [here](http://setiabud.blogspot.com/2010/08/stringlength-validator-into-maxlength.html) - where the display template pull the string-length validator (if exist) and add html properties accordingly. Here is the relevant code:

```
IEnumerable<ModelValidator> validators = ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.GetValidators(ViewData.ModelMetadata, ViewContext);
ModelClientValidationRule stringLengthRule = validators.SelectMany(v => v.GetClientValidationRules()).FirstOrDefault(m => m.ValidationType == "stringLength");
```